# gluLookAt function won't work

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

I'm trying to change the position/viewing angle of the camera in a scene, but no matter what I input, it just shows the default view set in my reshape function (below)

```
    void myReshape(int w, int h){
        glViewport(0,0,w,h);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();

        gluPerspective(40,w/h,.5, 1000);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Every other problem with this function is usually the result of improper push-pop matrix or making translations/rotations after or before calling it. I don't think I have any of these issues though. This is my display function.

```
    void myDisplay(){

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0, 1, 0);
  printf("Error: %x", glGetError());
  glPushMatrix(); //save current matrix
  glLoadIdentity(); //initialize new temp matrix to Identity
  glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-20); //move object back to origin
  glScalef(g_vLandScale[1],g_vLandScale[1],g_vLandScale[1]);  //perform transformations
  glRotatef(g_vLandRotate[1]/float(10), 0.0,1.0,0);
  glRotatef(g_vLandRotate[0]/float(10), 1.0,0,0);
  glRotatef(g_vLandRotate[2]/float(10),0,0,1);
  glTranslatef(g_vLandTranslate[0], 0.0,0.0);
  glTranslatef(0.0,g_vLandTranslate[1],0.0);
  glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,20); //move back to original position

    renderSplines();
  renderCrossBeams();
  renderGround();
  renderSky();

    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Any ideas on why this wont work? It just skips over the line entirely and doesn't change a thing about the scene. I've tried putting it before, after, using variables, using hardcoded numbers, using ints,floats,doubles, Glfloats, Gldoubles, putting it inside the push/pop block, nothing seems to work.

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_.

Comment: Hmmm... it looks like you are cancelling the effect of the `gluLookAt()` call by pushing another matrix on top of it and calling `glLoadIdentity()` again. Try placing it right before the first `glTranslatef()`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I think it would be alright to keep both tags, because this question would be valid in both a C and a C++ question

Comment: @Nasser: [That's not how it works.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216251/155739)

Comment: you pretty much just need to remove the line `glLoadIdentity(); //initialize new temp matrix to Identity`